# Fermat’s last Theorem $n=4$

Tags: number-theory

I’m revising for my upcoming number theory exam and there is usually an essay style question on it regarding Fermat’s last Theorem, UFD and the method of descent. However, sometimes there have been questions where you’ve had to comment on the difficulties arising from extending $n$ to larger numbers. Could someone maybe just bullet point of the problems that do arise because I (obviously wrongly) thought that the case $n=4$ was easier to prove than the case $n=3$.

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: What are the problems that arise from extending Fermat’s last Theorem to larger values of $n$. I know that for the case $n=4$ it’s easier to prove that $x^4 +y^4=z^2$ has no non trivial integer solutions and then the method of descent implies that $x^4+y^4=z^4$ has non non tirival integer solutions, but why is this true and why is it easier to prove?

Comment: $n=4$ is indeed easier than $n=3$, which is due to Euler. But this doesn't meaning anything for general $n$. And in general, such easy arguments are not enough for FLT.